# How does GRUB find /boot partition on an MBR disk?

Tags: boot, grub

Things I've discovered so far (possibly inaccurate):

- GRUB installs `boot.img` in the first sector (MBR) of a disk.
- GRUB installs `core.img` in the post-MBR gap.
- `boot.img` is loaded by BIOS and then loads `core.img` and transfers control to it.

But in the next step, how does `core.img` find the `/boot` partition? There may be multiple partitions on a disk so how does the core image correctly identify which is `/boot`? Is that hardcoded in the core image or does it do a search every time?

Additional research reveals there is a `--boot-directory` option in `grub-install` which lets you choose where to install GRUB. But the core image still has to find this partition at boot time. Again it needs some form of identifier. Is that a label, a UUID, or anything else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The address is hard coded in `core.img`. `core.img` has all the kernel and Grub modules necessary to call the Stage 2 modules by file path. You specify this as `(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub`. By default it'll try to load the `normal` module at `(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod` (assuming i386-pc arch).

[More details here.](http://www.dolda2000.com/~fredrik/doc/grub2)

Comment: @gilles thanks for the formatting edit! Though, I did mean 'kernel modules' not 'grub modules'.
Stage 1.5 consists of: diskboot.img+kernel.img+pc.mod+ext2.mod (the core image), so it contains modules in the kernel that you need to initialize your disk controllers for example, this gets compiled in as well. Given that it contains both though, I'll propose an edit as 'kernel ad Grub modules'